# Is it possible to survive the destruction of a planet (earth)?

Tags: energy, particle-physics, gravity, cosmology

I recently watched `Star Trek VI: The Undiscovered Country` again. The main story evolves around the destruction of a moon of the klingon empire which is their main energy production site. The moon practically explodes into pieces. Some of those pieces are fairly large.
After the destruction an emergency message is sent from the moon, apparently from one of the remaining pieces, until abruptly being canceled.

Now this is all fiction. Yet I wonder:
Is it possible to survive such a scenario and for how long? Let's say a large scale asteroid actually hits earth leading, however likely, to it being split into several larger pieces.
What will happen? It must affect gravity very fast, mustn't it? Also I wonder if atmosphere is instantly lost or will wrap around the resulting pieces? And maybe other factors should be considered too like a drastic temperature change or similar.

I'm sorry if this question is not very scientific or even in the wrong place here. But I thought this might be the most appropriate place to ask.

Comment: It's nonsense.  The entire scene is dreadfully bad, not least of which is the idea of the shockwave hitting the very distant starship.  Anything that powerful would obliterate the moon it originated on, never mind what the shockwave was supposed to be composed of.

Comment: Yeah, and let's not start about the shaking of the cup that is destroyed on the bridge of the starfleet vessel. Anyway my questions is not about the likeliness of such an event ^^

Comment: Btw. here is the scence: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sI8U8zwlZbw

Comment: You speak of the Earth breaking into pieces as if it was a solid object. But it's not. It's a big blob of molten lava with a thin rocky skin, and a smaller solid center.

Comment: I know, that's why I wrote "however likely". Let's just assume it's somehow possible.

Comment: Survive a destruction! By definition they are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 2):

Not likely.

That force that can caus earth to split into pieces will firstly create incredibly strong shockwaves which would kill anyone.

Anyone lucky enought to survive that will probably died bcoz of terrible earthquakes, splitting earth will cause pieces of earth to be thrown into space with very bi velocities, just an acceleration will kill you. Every piece of earth thrown into space with some living beeing would die of suffocation.

Anyone even more lucky and still connected to "dissasembled earth" would die of burning atmosfere (coz of impact) or soon by suffocating because atmosfere will be filled will all kind of dust.

Its hard to think about what would happen, but, even asteroids not big enought to split earth into pieces would be able to kill us very fast.

Asteroids with a size of 1mile radius hitting earth will cause some serious damage to earth over time(to enviroment and living beeings).

Conclusion (tldr)

That kind of asteroid would kill us all, quickly.
It would thrown earth from suns orbit...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the earth will lose it's atmosphere as it has been hit by asteriods many times in its history. The most dangerous immediate effect would be the complete annihilation of the country or larger landmass where it hits. It will cause large scale tsunamis and earthquakes which will cause catastrophic effects. The impact will cause a large mass of dust to rise and cause a long winter which will last several years. Volcanic eruptions will probably destroy countries like Indonesia and Japan. All agricultural processes would cease and the people who survive would probably wish for their death.
We may be able to survive underground if we have enough supplies but we would be pushed into the stone age again as all our infrastructure and institutions would be gone. And life like that won't be worth living.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I'm not talking about an asteroid hitting the earth causing a lot of surface damage. I talk about planet earth actually breaking into pieces.

Comment: I believe we can't survive that event while living on this planet. We would need to find some other planet or moon to migrate to.